# Custom CSS Lightning Web Components - Remove Outline from Input Field

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-design-system, lightning-web-components

If, for instance, an input field is rendered with `lightning-input`, and I want to add custom styling e.g. a border color to or remove the outline from the input field. How can I do that? I have tried assigning a class to;

`<ligtning-input class="custom-input"></lightning-input>`

and then styling the class but seems not to be working.

Comment: Seems like you are not setting CSS class in proper way, have you defined the CSS in CSS file? Adding `class="slds-has-error` to input works which is a standard SLDS class. If error persists, I would encourage to add a minimal version of code with which we can reproduce the error and help you further.

Comment: You cant actually modify namespaced component styling because of shadow dom and encapsulation. You will have to get used to that when working with lwc’s